# WebdriverIO can't click on (Ionic) tab

Tags: ionic-framework, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I'm using WebdriverIO to test some basic functionality on an Ionic (+ Angular) application. The framework setup works all right, but I can't find a way to `click` on certain HTML elements. For instance, this is some HTML sample:

```
<div class="tabbar show-tabbar" role="tablist" style="top: 166px; display: flex;">
  <a class="tab-button has-title has-title-only" href="#" role="tab" id="tab-t0-0" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-0"
      aria-selected="true">
    <span class="tab-button-text">Blah</span>
    <div class="button-effect"></div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab-button has-title has-title-only" href="#" role="tab" id="tab-t0-1" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-1"
      aria-selected="false">
    <span class="tab-button-text">Foo</span>
    <div class="button-effect"
        style="transform: translate3d(83px, -103px, 0px) scale(1); height: 240px; width: 240px; opacity: 0; transition: transform 395ms ease 0s, opacity 277ms ease 118ms;"></div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab-button has-title has-title-only" href="#" role="tab" id="tab-t0-2" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-2"
      aria-selected="false">
    <span class="tab-button-text">Bar</span>
    <div class="button-effect"
        style="transform: translate3d(3px, -99px, 0px) scale(1); height: 240px; width: 240px; opacity: 0; transition: transform 395ms ease 0s, opacity 277ms ease 118ms;"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="tab-highlight animate" style="transform: translate3d(570px, 0px, 0px) scaleX(285);"></div>
</div>
```

And this is a super-simple test case that I'm doing to test the functionality:

```
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("Some Test", () => {
  const logingUrl: string = "url0";

  const appUrl: string = "url1";

  it("Some Test Again", () => {
    browser.url(logingUrl);
    browser.url(appUrl);
    const tab = $("#tab-t0-2");
    tab.click();
    expect(tab.getAttribute("aria-selected")).to.equal("true");
  });
});
```

..but every time I run it, I get some weird error message that the element is no clickable at some point. Any clues?

```
[0-0] element click intercepted in "Some Test Again"
element click intercepted: Element <a class="tab-button has-title has-title-only" href="#" role="tab" id="tab-t0-2" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-2" aria-selected="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (666, 170). Other element would receive the click: <ion-backdrop disable-activated="" role="presentation" tappable="" class="backdrop-no-tappable" style="opacity: 0.5;"></ion-backdrop>
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those classic Angular/Ionic backdrop gotcha's.

Let's start with the error message: *element `#tab-t0-2` is not clickable at point (coordinates), another element would receive the click: `ion-backdrop`*.

This tells us that your targeted element cannot be clicked as the `ion-backdrop` tag is rendered on top of it. The [ion-backdrop](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/backdrop) component is a short animation (*usually used for modals*), in this case, the semi dimming of the background (`opacity: 0.5`).

**✖ Solution 1:** Easy way to counter it? Explicitly expect for it to disappear, then click the targeted element.

```
it("Some Test Again", () => {
  browser.url(logingUrl);
  browser.url(appUrl);

  // Explicitly wait for the backdrop animation to disappear:
  const backdrop = $('.backdrop-no-tappable');
  backdrop.waitForExist(5000, true, 'Backdrop still present');

  const tab = $("#tab-t0-2");
  tab.click();
  expect(tab.getAttribute("aria-selected")).to.equal("true");
});
```

**✖ Solution 2:** Another thing you can try is **only** click on the `tab` element, once it is fully visible and intractable in the DOM (*this is kind of a best-practice*):

```
  const tab = $("#tab-t0-2");
  tab.waitForDisplayed(5000);
  // For 'wdio-v4' users: 
  // tab.waitForVisible(5000);
  tab.click();
  expect(tab.getAttribute("aria-selected")).to.equal("true");
```

Comment: Thanks, @iamdanchiv! That helped me. I ended up using a "merged" version: `$("ion-backdrop.backdrop-no-tappable").waitForExist(undefined, true)` ;)